# How does tf.layers.dense create the inputs.kernel weight matrix?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

[Tensorflow document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense): 
`outputs = activation(inputs.kernel + bias)`

1. The document states `kernel` is a weights matrix created by the layer, but I cannot find the implementation of `kernel` in [tensorflow/python/layers/core.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.9/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py). Where will I  find the implementation?

----------------------------tl;dr-------------------------------------

From the answer, the shape of weight matrix is defined as `shape=[input_shape[-1].value, self.units]` [Line 886](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.9/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L878-L921)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have started mixing `tf.layers` with `tf.keras`. In you referenced implementation the class inherits all methods from [`keras_layers`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.9/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py#L37)

"Following the money", the implementation is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.9/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L878-L921) and boils down to

```
def build(...):
    self.kernel = self.add_variable('kernel', ...
    self.bias = self.add_variable
def call(...):
    # ...
    outputs = gen_math_ops.mat_mul(inputs, self.kernel)
    # ...
    if self.activation is not None:
        return self.activation(outputs)
    return outputs
```